# Order of operations general

Tags: logic, arithmetic

I have a question regarding the history of the hierarchy of operations. Why do multiplication and division have the same hierarchy? And even more so why operate from left to right, if they have the same hierarchy. Furthermore, all mathematicians accept this hierarchy.

I understand that the rules are not theorems, but what they are based on, or why they are taught, beyond removing ambiguity from the expressions.

My doubt comes from seeing many people divided into saying that $8\div2(2 + 2)$ is $16$ and others say that it is $1$. For me, due to the hierarchy of operations that I know, it must be 16. Also, I have seen that they commented on videos from another platform, which was a simple algorithm, which is not true. I really do not understand what you mean by saying that the algorithm is not true.

In conclusion, I would like to know if there are even logical reasons why the rules are "correct", and if not what are the reasons for the detractors of the hierarchy of operations.

Comment: My best guess is that it’s a mix of “historical accident” and “basically all options are equally arbitrary, so we just picked one and went with it.” Though with regards to the expression you’ve shown above - I’ve never encountered something like that in practice, except in the context of programming languages where having a more rigid interpretation of the rules is par for the course.

Comment: $+$ and $-$ are in a sense inverses of each other, as are $*$ and $/$, so it makes sense for the operators in each of these pairs to "bind as tightly" (have the same precedence). It's a convention, no doubt the right one,  that $*$ and $/$ bind more tightly than $+$ and $-$. As for default order of evaluation: Western languages are  written and read from left to right.

Comment: In higher algebra there is no subtraction, only adding negative numbers nor is there any division, only multiplication by reciprocals. This is because multiplication and addition are associative while division and subtraction are not. This reduces them to the same operation, and so the same level of evaluation.

Comment: Re: your expression $8\div2(2 + 2)$. It should be noted that many people intuitively distinguish between times $a x b$ and juxtaposition $ab$ or $a(b)$ and rank the latter, juxtaposition, as higher precedence than the former, times, and than division, so that's why they evaluate the result as $1$.